# WebRTC and NAT Traversal

Tags: webrtc, traversal, nat

I would like to use WebRTC with HTML and Javascript on the client side and then have a server written in
Javascript or even C on my server side. I will be happy to use either a Linux or a Windows Server.
I don't want to use a remote server. I would like to perform the NAT traversal locally on my own server.
I have WebRTC running peer-to-peer without NAT traversal and it is very effective.
It is possible to have WebRTC running and do the NAT traversal myself on the local machine?

Comment: You can run your own STUN/TURN servers, if that’s what you mean. They’ll need to be reachable by both peers, by definition.

Answer (score 0):

For WebRTC an ICE Agent just needs a 3-Tuple on each side (IP/Port/Protocol).

Your C server just needs to publish an address that is reachable by the WebRTC Agent in the browser. You have a couple different choices.

- You can use a STUN server and establish a NAT Mapping
- You can run your server on a internet routable address, and don't need to worry about mapping
- You can do port forwarding. Your server can be in a NAT, but will be world routable on a range of ports
- You can use something like NAT-PMP or PCP

ICE (the protocol that WebRTC uses) doesn't care where the candidates come from. It just works on finding a route that works.